# The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job

In my **web application level feature**, its activated, but unable to see teh timer job in the timerjob definitions, in **monitoring**
so i went with activating feature with powershell,  receiving this error:

Getting error while activating  timer job  feature:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> E:\PoCSolutions\enable-feature-TestingTimerJob-Feature.ps1
>   enable-spfeature : The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url http://srvr1:28516/.

- enable-spfeature -Identity "TestingTimerJobFeature" -Url "http://srvr01: ...
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etEnableFeature:SPCmdletEnableFeature) [Enable-SPFeature], SPCmdletException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature

```
  private bool CreateJob(SPWebApplication site)
      {
          bool jobCreated = false;
         try
        {
            TestingSPTimerJob.TestingSPTimer timerjobrilt1 = new 
            TestingSPTimerJob.TestingSPTimer(JobName, site);  
            SPDailySchedule jobDailySchedule = new SPDailySchedule();
            jobDailySchedule.BeginHour = 24;
            jobDailySchedule.BeginMinute = 02;
            jobDailySchedule.BeginSecond = 1;

            timerjobrilt1.Schedule = jobDailySchedule;
            timerjobrilt1.Update();
         }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return jobCreated;
         }
         return jobCreated;
      }
```

#########################################################################
        public class TestingSPTimer :SPJobDefinition
          {

```
      public TestingSPTimer()
        : base()
        {        }

    public TestingSPTimer(string jobName, SPService service)
        : base(jobName, service, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
       {
        this.Title = "Testing SPTimerJob";
       }

      public TestingSPTimer(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp)
          : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
       {
        this.Title = "Testing SPTimerJob";
       }

      public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
      {
        SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

        string strwebappname = webApp.Name.ToString();


        foreach (SPSite singleSite in webApp.Sites)
        {
            if (singleSite.ContentDatabase.Id.Equals(targetInstanceId))
            {
                SPList objListProjRequest = 
        singleSite.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("TestingTimerJob");

                SPWeb objspweb = singleSite.RootWeb;

               SPListItem singleitemm=   objListProjRequest.Items.Add();

               singleitemm["Title"] = "Testingtimer_" + 
           DateTime.Now.ToString();

               singleitemm.Update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the following:

- Provide the **Feature Guid** rather than its name from `feature.xml` file
- You have provided the correct URL.
- Don't surround the feature with double quotation " as shown below

  ```
  Enable-SPFeature –Identity f9ce720e-6473-47c2-142k-9d94582369e –url $Url
  ```

Comment: I did the same .but still the timer job is not visible in the "timerjobdefinitipns" list .

Comment: what's your timer job do

Comment: REad the projectcode field values from list , based on a condition - if the target resolution date < todaysdate - then add those projectcode added into generics_list. Then using these project codes, i will navigate to another doc.lib , n apply item level permission on those matching project codes in the  doc.lib.

Comment: Do you tried to change the scope from web application to Site

Comment: No, while creating the feature ,i have selected the scope as webapplication. BTW, is there any way i can check the field called " target resolution date" is <  todays date ? Without implementing a timer job? I dont think, its possible using a eventreceiver unless someone explicitly update the list. So ,bcoz of this reason , i have chosen timer job to implement this functionality

Comment: is there anything to  do the environment? any services need to be restarted? anything specific to the timer job??

Comment: Sorry for late answer but let me first raise this issue on my side to try to solve it and provide you other options :) meanwhile try to change the from WebA to Site and feedback me please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61717/discussion-between-samolpp-and-m-qassas).